# wordpress php function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this php function in wordpress

```
function includePosts ($content = '') { 
    preg_match_all('/(?<=\\[\\[)\\d+?(?=\\]\\])/', $content, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $numMatches = count($matches[0]);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numMatches; $i++) {
        $postId = $matches[0][$i];
        $post= get_post($postId);
        $linkToPost = '<a href="'.get_permalink($postId).'">';  
        $postTitle = $post->post_title;
        $postTitleText = "<li> $linkToPost$postTitle</a></li>";
        $content = str_replace("[[$postId]]", $postTitleText, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
//  add_action('admin_menu', 'addAdminPage');
add_filter('the_content', 'includePosts', 1);
```

What this does is to bring the shortcode from the wordpress page, wich would be a post id and displays the title of that post between `<li>..<li>` Everything ok .. well not quite.
I want all the `<li> ... </li>` inside one `<ul>...</ul>`. Is it posible in this function?

---

jeremysawesome, one thing i forgot to mention `return $content` returns not only the `<li>` but also the content of the page where the shortcode is, but thank you for your time.

Tristar Web Design, your solution acts strange, I get something like this:

```
<ul>

   <li>...</li>

   <li>...</li>

      <ul>

        <li>...</li>

        <li>...</li>

     </ul>
</ul>
```

I really don't get it

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark. If you replace your return statement with the one below, does it accomplish what you would like?

```
return "<ul>$content</ul>";
```

Comment: That wouldn't work, that would wrap the whole content and the list elements in a ul

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
function includePosts ($content = '') { 
    preg_match_all('/(?<=\\[\\[)\\d+?(?=\\]\\])/', $content, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $numMatches = count($matches[0]);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numMatches; $i++) {
        $postId = $matches[0][$i];
        $post= get_post($postId);
        $linkToPost = '<a href="'.get_permalink($postId).'">';  
        $postTitle = $post->post_title;
        $ul = ($i == 0) ? '<ul>' : '';
        $endul = ($i == $numMatches) ? '</ul>' : '';
        $postTitleText = "$ul<li> $linkToPost$postTitle</a></li>$endul";
        $content = str_replace("[[$postId]]", $postTitleText, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
//  add_action('admin_menu', 'addAdminPage');
add_filter('the_content', 'includePosts', 1);
```

Not 100% sure this will work, but give it a try!